# How to Display something depending on variable given in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I need to show a word that is attributed to a number, in AngularJS.
Through the controller I send to the view a variable $game.complexity, and complexity can be a number from 1 to 4. I want to take that number and show it as a word:

1 ---> easy

2 --->medium

what I initially thought was that maybe it would work with a cutstom filter:

```
var filtersModule = angular.module("ttmatchApp.Filters", [])

filtersModule.filter("complexityFilter", function(){
    return function(value){
        switch(value)
        {
            case 1: 
                return "easy"
                break;
            case 2:
                return "medium"
                break;
            case 3:
                return "hard"
                break;
            case 4:
                return "very hard"
                break;  

        }

    }
})
```

and call it like this:

```
<p>{{game.complexity | complexityFilter:game.complexity}} complexity</p></div>
```

i also tried it like this:

```
<p>{{game.complexity | complexityFilter}} complexity</p></div>
```

I define `$scope.game` within a controller, and i give it the necessary data through a json file. Other scope elements such as `game.name` work well, and show.

the `filtersModule` is also linked to the main module.

Do i have to introduce the filter to the controller as well?

Am i using the wrong method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once game.complexity is evaluated in the expression, it is outputted as a string. That means that your switch case should be on strings and not integers - "1" instead of 1, etc..

Edit: I was wrong, the expression is evaluated into a string, but the filter is still within that expression, so it receives game.complexity still as a number. The problem was what you solved in the comments.

Comment: i actually tried that as well, it doesn't show anything. and do i have to send the value in the view to the filter? which of the two ways is the correct one?

Comment: The second form is the correct one. If you had additional parameters you can use ':' like in your first form to pass them, but you have only one. Can you please put a plunker\jsfiddle that shows your problem?

Comment: it's weird, i made a simplified version of my code in plunkr and it works...but it still doesn't on my code. i'll try to look for unlinked stuff